# A terminal which provides select-to-copy and right-click-to-paste

Tags: gnome-terminal

In putty/cygwin my config is:

- select in console -> copies to clipboard
- right click -> pastes from clipboard.

Was after a terminal in Linux which might provide me with both of these features?  I haven't been able to find one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can copy and paste into terminal, you you have to select it from a dropdown list when you press right-mouse button.

Comment: Yup, have seen that.  Was after something which was faster, and more to the way I usually work.  Thanks.

Comment: http://blog.tremende.com/2016/04/02/copy-on-select-and-right-click-paste-in-linux-terminal/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solution with Terminator from [this site](http://www.hoab.fr/article31/right-click-paste-on-linux-terminal-with-terminator).

```
sudo vi /usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminal.py
```

Look for function : on_buttonpress

Revert button test (*contextual menu* go to middle click, *paste* on right click) :

```
def on_buttonpress(self, widget, event):
    ...
    if event.button == 1:
        ...
    elif event.button == 3:
        ...
    elif event.button == 2:
        ...

    return(False)
```

Now waiting for the [feature request on Terminator](https://answers.launchpad.net/terminator/+question/241771) :)

Comment: Excellent - thanks for finding a solution to this without arguing that the requester should change their behaviour.

Comment: Looks like the feature request is now in - "PuTTY style paste" on the global tab.

Answer (score 62):

Most of the terminals seem to use copy on select and middle-button to paste selection, or emulated middle-button to paste (using both mouse buttons at once).   This is typical Unix behavior, and the emulation is the updated usage required by Microsoft-type mice with only two buttons or two buttons and a scrollwheel.

The mouse buttons could be remapped with xinput or other means.  This will differ from version to version and on different mouse models.  See the [Ubuntu community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto) for that.

Also see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6404/how-to-fix-my-middle-mouse-button-being-recognized-as-left-mouse-button), which is the reverse of the procedure you'd need.

Terminals I have that use select to copy and middle to paste include Gnome terminal, xfce terminal, Eterm, plain xterm, uxterm, rxvt, mrxvt, and aterm.  I'm sure there are others.

My primary terminal, terminator (use apt-get or the software center to install), lets you choose copy on select as an option (with a single click):

Open preference and click the 'copy on select' box :

[image: terminator preferences]

Comment: Any idea how to make this the default terminal in gnome?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the clipboard used when selecting text is different to that of an explicit copy (via keyboard shortcut or menu item). To paste from this keyboard you must use the middle mouse button, and not keyboard shortcut or menu. This is different behaviour to Putty on Windows.

Comment: Yaay for Terminator! Now I can copy and paste happy town with all my macros without an extra copy key press. I hightlighted it.... I want it copied. Yay!

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mattrose/terminator

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install terminator

and then, right-click on the terminator's black screen and change the @belacqua

Answer (score 47):

press the middle scroll wheel, man.

Comment: I love short and precise answers!

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a solution for gnome-terminal.

Comment: ok ok, I forgot to do that

Comment: Not so useful on a laptop

Comment: You press both left and right keys on laptop touchpad for that

Answer (score 15):

To save some time for those who are checking, the terminals below don't support this feature.

- [gnome-terminal](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal) 3.6.2 (C, GPL), [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=739215)
- [sakura](https://launchpad.net/sakura) 3.1.3 (C, GTK+, GPLv2), [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sakura/+bug/1366513)

Comment: Both bug reports are marked as "won't fix", sadly.

Comment: @mwfearnley maybe becayse they use the same base library that upstream doesn't want to patch. I could make a list of those, but not now.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure which terminal you're using right now but the default terminal in Ubuntu allows you to copy and paste. In your desktop environment select the text you want to copy and press ctrl+shift+c. If you have something in your clipboard that you want to paste, put the cursor in the right position and press ctrl+shift+v.

The other option is as Dr_Bunsen comments above says, both options are available in the right mouse button dropdown list.

Comment: You did not read the question, did you?

Answer (score 4):

I use a non-free application with exactly that feature:

[VanDyke.com > Products > SecureCRT](http://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/index.html)

It support left-button select or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (to clipboard), and right-button or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (to paste).  I use either, depending on how keyboard- or mouse- centric the task is.

**SecureCRT** also supports pre-configured login (scripts), multiple sessions (tabs/windows), and full scripting (extensibility).  I find that when doing a lot of remote support, across multiple sites, these extra features are critical.

I have used it for years on Windows (or under Ubuntu + Wine), but it was ported to Linux in early 2011.  I have not yet found a free alternate with all the features it offers.

Comment: Looks like a really cool terminal.  Such a shame that it costs so much.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Using the default Gnome terminal, if I highlight text then press my mouse wheel it will paste whatever is highlighted.

Hope this works for others. I liked this feature when I was (forced) to use a Windows desktop and putty.

Comment: This answer was already given and does not add information.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but newer versions of Terminator support putty-style behaviour. Right-click --> Preferences --> Putty style paste.

Remember that you will no longer be able to right-click to get to Preferences since that is now mapped to paste. To open Preferences, use Shift-middle button.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

It's not everything you want, but a middle-click in Gnome Terminal takes the place of the right-click - it does a copy-and-paste (using the clipboard) on selected text, and pastes otherwise.

I don't think there's any equivalent way to just copy though - the right-click context menu seems to be the closest option.

Answer (score 1):

Another terminal that would work and hasn't been mentioned here is Gnome Connection Manager: http://kuthulu.com/gcm/

This is actually my personal favourite because it allows you to connect to multiple machines in a very user friendly way.

You can set it up to automatically copy selected text, and text can be pasted using right click.

Answer (score 1):

If right-click paste in your terminal accidentally broken, this could happens after updating gnome >=3.9

Solution is here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ#How_can_I_make_middle-click_paste_the_primary_selection.3F

```
# ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
[Settings]
gtk-enable-primary-paste=true
```

Comment: Thx, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For gnome-terminal a patch exists: https://github.com/jrnewell/ubuntu-gnome-terminal-patch to copy-paste in putty-style.

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 + GNOME Shell 3.18.5 with LightDm. It works!

**Upd:** Updated for Ubuntu 18 here: https://github.com/sasha-ch/ubuntu-gnome-terminal-patch . Feedback are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

[mate-terminal](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-terminal) is very similar to the stock gnome-terminal, and it supports shift-highlighting + middle click.

Then, afterwards, do yourself a favour and install a [Base16](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16) color package. Personally, I like [this one](https://github.com/HashBang173/base16-mate-terminal) with the Solar Flare Dark profile loaded.

Comment: OP did not ask for middle click, and middle click is not the same as right click

Answer (score 0):

Tested in terminator installation on top of cgywin, the "terminal.py" is located in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/terminatorlib/terminal.py

search for "rightclick" and change elif options as follow will do the same as mentioned in the early post.

```
elif event.button == 3:
    # rightclick should paste the clipboard
    self.paste_clipboard(True)
    return(True)
elif event.button == 2:
    # middleclick should display a context menu if Ctrl is  not pressed
    if event.state & gtk.gdk.CONTROL_MASK == 0:
        self.popup_menu(widget, event)
        return(True)
```