# How can we copy and paste in GNOME Terminal in the same way as in PuTTY, i.e. select to copy, right click to paste?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, putty

I am using GNOME Ubuntu Desktop Environment. Right now I have to select the text and then right click on it and then have to select copy option, and the same is the case for paste as well.

Using PuTTY terminal from Windows, once you select any text, it'll be copied. And to paste it we will have to just right click. Can we do similar settings on Ubuntu as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3348800/4493879

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A terminal which provides select-to-copy and right-click-to-paste](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211292/a-terminal-which-provides-select-to-copy-and-right-click-to-paste)

Comment: @Graham I don't think this is a duplicate since this question is about `gnome-terminal`

Comment: To quickly copy text you can just select it and then *middle-click* (for many mice that’s pressing the mouse wheel down) where you want to paste it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the double-click copy with a 3rd party app [clipit](https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt)

but the possible downside is it applies system wide not just gnome-terminal

`sudo apt install clipit`

when using Clipit:

1. Right click on clipit icon in tray
2. Preferences
3. Settings
4. check: Use Primary selections and Synchronize clipboards.

and you're good to go you can double click in terminal and it's in your clipboard

Comment: Synchronizing clipboards doesn’t enable paste on right click, does it?

Comment: no that's unrelated i don't have any solution for the right-click paste