# Middle mouse button will not paste

Tags: xorg

I have a Logitech M560 mouse, but I do not know how to map the middle button to pasting, as is default in my other mouse.

I ran 'xev' and clicked the middle button in the white box. The output includes 'button 1'. So, I want to map button 1 to the 'paste selection' as clicking the right and left mouse buttons simultaneously does with my mouse now.

Comment: That should happen out of the box. What version of Ubuntu is this? What desktop environment? Does clicking left and right buttons simultaneously paste?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10. Oh, yes! I wasn't aware of this feature. I guess I can just get used to clicking the right and left buttons simultaneously instead of the middle mouse button!

Comment: That feature is how it used to work back before wheel mice were that common, when mice only had two buttons. Do you have an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file? You say that middle click pasting does work with another mouse of yours?

Comment: I see... This xorg.conf file does not exist on my machine.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't by default, I was wondering if you had created one.  It's a file that allows you to configure your X system (the GUI basically) and the mouse can also be configured there. Anyway, please [edit] your question and include `xev` info. You need to run `xev` and then middle click in the white window. Your output will include the button number, it will be something like `ButtonPress event`, blah blah, `state 0x2010, button 2, same_screen YES` we need to know which button the middle click is reported as just in case the issue is a wrong button reported.

Comment: @terdon I edited the question, please let me know how to proceed next. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check out this one? http://askubuntu.com/a/6634/169736 Also, edit your question and include the output of `xinput list device_name` being device name the one that identifies itself as pointer when you only run `xinput`, like this http://paste.ubuntu.com/7272164/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue today (2016-08-29).  It is unclear what caused it since I didn't upgrade anything in the past 4 days.

Rebooting didn't help.

Key observation: `xev` wasn't showing any event coming from the mouse when clicking the middle mouse button (scrollwheel) inside the `xev` little square. This indicated some low-level driver issue as opposed to an application config issue.

Mouse selection was working fine: clicking <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> or running `xsel` from a terminal were both pasting the current selection.

Only the pasting via the middle mouse button didn't work.  The problem affected all applications, including firefox and terminals.

Eventually, this fixed it for me.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xorg
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my configuration:

```
~$ cat .xbindkeysrc |egrep -v "^$|^#"
"xte 'mouseclick 2'"
    m:0x50 + c:134
```

In this way if made "*work*" the middle button.

I choose the text I need to copy/paste while holding the right button, after choosing where to paste I click button. If need to paste again the same text, since the square button doesn't raise the same events every time, I'll click it quickly twice.

If you select another text the event scattered from the square button is always the one that makes xte to emulate the middle click.

Is not perfect but better than not having middle click at all.